# clarification needed on Java's 32-bit integer representation system?

Tags: java, integer, bit-manipulation, bit

I need some clarifications regarding the binary representation of decimal in Java (or any other language for that matter).

pardon, if this is too basic, but I need to understand it thoroughly.

```
x = 31 is represented in Java 32 bit as:

x — > 00000000 00000000 00000000 00011111  // 

the binary to decimal conversion is achieved by:
                               2^4+2^3+2^2+2^1+2^0=31
```

Now, if you consider all the bits turned on, except the `signed bit (most significant bit)`, we get

```
y -> 01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111

and binary to decimal conversion by summing powers of 2 will be:
        2^31+2^30………+2^3+2^2+2^1+2^0=4294967295.
```

however, if you do:

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("1111111111111111111111111111111",2));
you get: 2147483647 which is 2^31-1
```

so it means, the when `31 bits` are turned on, I do not get the additive sum of the powers of 2.
why is this?

may be I did not understand something, if some one could clarify that will be very helpful.

In case this helps:
All the two raise powers till 31 are in this list:

```
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768, 65536, 131072, 262144, 524288, 1048576, 2097152, 4194304, 8388608, 16777216, 33554432, 67108864, 134217728, 268435456, 536870912, 1073741824, 2147483648]
```

EDIT: I corrected the `y`-representation, now it has 32 bits, but if you calculate the 31 bits that are turned on with summing the powers, you would get 4294967295. I have one liner in python here

```
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [pow(2,i) for i in range(32)])
4294967295
```

Comment: Your string only has 31 `1`s in it, not 32.

Comment: Take a look at [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: The java spec states, 
"int: By default, the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, which has a minimum value of -2^31 and a maximum value of 2^31-1."

Comment: @JonSkeet: The first `0` is default, with and without it, I get the same results. so you see only 31 bits there

Comment: @user1988876: Imagine you had 3 1s, so "111". That would be 1 + 2 + 4, which is 2^3 - 1. Any expression of "1" `n` times (where n is 31 or less) will give you 2^n - 1.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yeah, I put that (or at least the observation that there are 32 1s) in my answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I updated with correction and edited the post

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: please see my edit, that typo of mistakenly including an extra one, does not make it invalid

Comment: @user1988876 The statement about the sum in my answer still stands.

Comment: @user1988876: Your edit doesn't address my point at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that here:

```
y -> 011111111 11111111 11111111 11111111

and binary to decimal conversion by summing powers of 2 will be:
        2^31+2^30………+2^3+2^2+2^1+2^0=4294967295.
```

you've put one too many 1s. As Jon Skeet mentioned in the comments, you should have only 31 1s, not 32. Thus, the sum should start at 2^30, not 2^31.

(**Update**: Well, you've updated that bit to have the correct number of 1s. My statement about the sum though, still stands. **It should start at 2<sup>30</sup>, not 2<sup>31</sup>.**)

When you did this part:

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("1111111111111111111111111111111",2));
you get: 2147483647 which is 2^31-1
```

you have the number of 1s correct (31).

Comment: I have only 31 1s in the system.out.println. I double checked the counting. If I have 32 ones, I turn on the first bit correct, I want to represent the +ve integer, so the first bit is `0` and hence 31 1s

Comment: @user1988876 Right. What I'm saying is that you had it right in the `System.out.println`, but you had it wrong elsewhere.

Comment: yes, I actually understood reading both of yours and Jonskeets posts. your explanation was really useful.

Answer (score 3):

> so it means, the when 31 bits are turned on, I do not get the additive sum of the powers of 2.

Yes you do - you get 2<sup>0</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup> + ... + 2<sup>30</sup>... which is 2<sup>31</sup> - 1, exactly as you're seeing.

You're *not* adding 2<sup>31</sup> because that would be represented by a 32nd `1`, at which point you'd be beyond the limit of what an `int` can represent in Java.

It's probably easier to consider smaller numbers. Suppose you have 5 bits - your example earlier on:

```
Integer.parseInt("11111")
```

That would print out 31, exactly as you said before... because 31 is 2<sup>5</sup> - 1.

So for `n` bits all set to 1, you get 2<sup>n</sup> - 1... which is correct for your example with 31 bits. There's nothing inconsistent here.

Comment: I see it now, somehow I was counting the bits the turned on and raising the total bits turned to power of two, but since the representation starts from 2^0, I need to reduce by 1

Comment: @user1988876: Yes, exactly.

Comment: Guess I should still work on my explaining; I've been trying to stress that all along. >.<

Comment: @JonSkeet: the python code is not a problem the range(32) gives a list from [0,31] both inclusive, but I should have range(31), which will give [0,30] inclusive, and summing them indeed give the correct answer! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
y -> 01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
----------------------------------------
     31       23       15       7
```

The number is the index of the most significant bit in each byte.

So `0x2^31 + 1x2^30 + 1x2^29 + ... + 1x2^0 = 2147483647`

You were simply going one bit too far.

You can actually test this

```
int a = 0b01111111_11111111_11111111_11111111;
System.out.println(a);
```

prints

```
2147483647
```

Comment: Thanks, my mistake started with raising the power of two directly with the bits turned on..yours and others here explained well,

Comment: @user1988876 You're welcome. Some times you just need to visualize it in different ways.